# Could you lend me any/a little/../money?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, uncountable-nouns

I would like to know how to say that correctly and whether some/any could stand as a subject in the sentence:

Could you lend me ... money? Sure, If I find some/any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way to ask this question is "*Could you lend me some money*?" You aren't asking a question, you are making a request, therefore **some** is the word to be used. Similarly, when you offer someone something, you don't use **any** but **some**, for example: "*Would you like some money*?" In both cases you sort of expect the answer to be positive.

As for the answer to this question, both "*If I find some*" and "*If I find any*" are correct, but in the latter you indicate that the possibilities to find the money aren't many.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *some* or *any* in the leading question, but I would favor *some* instead of *any* in the response:

> Could you lend me some money?
>   Sure, if I could find some...

or:

> Could you lend me any money?
>   Sure, if I could find some...

Why?  Both words are relatively close in meaning, and both can be used as adjectives or pronouns (which is how they are being used in the first and second sentences, respectively).  But look at the nuances in meaning:

> ***some***
>   3. (adj) of a certain unspecified number, amount, degree, etc.: *to some extent*.
>   7. (pronoun) an unspecified number, amount, etc., as distinguished from the rest or in addition: *He paid a thousand dollars and then
>   some*
>
> ***any***
>   3. (adj) in whatever quantity or number, great or small; some: *Do you have any butter?*
>   6. (pronoun)an unspecified person or persons; anybody; anyone: *He does better than any before him*.
>   7. (pronoun) a single one or ones; an unspecified thing or things; a quantity or number: *We don't have any left.*

In the answer, you are essentially saying, "Sure, I would lend you some money, if I had an unspecified amount of money."

```
meanings from Dictionary.com
```